# How to pass a UI element to a new fabric canvas within a Marionette ItemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fabricjs, marionette

I want to use Fabric.js and Marionette.js v2.4.7.

I have error

```
Cannot create property 'style' on string 'constructor'
```

I'm trying to use `this.ui.canva` but have error

```
Cannot set property 'userSelect' of undefined
```

### ItemView

```
define([
    'app',
    'marionette',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'pace',
    'text!templates/constructor/index.ejs',
    'fabric'
], function (App, Marionette, Backbone, _, pace, constructorTmpl, fabric) {
    'use strict';

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: _.template(constructorTmpl),
        ui: {
            canva: '#constructor'
        },
        onRender: function () {
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('constructor');
        }
    });
});
```

### index.ejs

```
<canvas id="constructor" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: How is this ItemView added to DOM?

Comment: ItemView have template - template: _.template(constructorTmpl),

Comment: Isn't that just in memory? Is this part of a collection view that is in DOM or something? I'm wondering where this is attached to DOM? Fabric is probably not able to find the element by id because it's not in DOM but in memory

Comment: It's item of collection. Solve problem  by using `setTimeout(function () {
                var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('constructor'); },0);` but it's not good solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the view's element is not in the DOM yet, fabric can't globally find the element with id `constructor`.

But the element already exist in memory inside the view and you can use it. `fabric.Canvas` can take a DOM element instead of a string.

In Marionette versions before v3, the [`ItemView` takes care of calling `bindUIElements`](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.view.html#viewbinduielements) and they are made [available directly in the `ui` hash](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.itemview.html#organizing-ui-elements).

```
onRender: function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.ui.canva[0]);
}
```

[In Marionette v3 and up](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.3.1/marionette.view.html#marionetteview)

> Note: From Marionette v3.x, `Marionette.View` replaces
>   `Marionette.LayoutView` and `Marionette.ItemView`.

Use [`getUI` view function](https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.3.1/marionette.view.html#accessing-ui-elements) to get the jQuery object of the UI element.

```
onRender: function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.getUI('canva')[0]);
}
```